# Make argument mandatory without relying on position

Tags: c++, initialization, constructor-injection

Say a class Foo has two dependencies (Bar and Baz), and that it is an error to construct a Foo without providing both of them. Constructor injection makes it easy to guarantee at compile time that this is done:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(const std::shared_ptr<Bar>& bar, const std::shared_ptr<Baz>& baz);
   // (don't get hung up on the type of pointer used; it's for example only)
};
```

But let's say Foo also needs two doubles:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::shared_ptr<Bar>& bar, const std::shared_ptr<Baz>& baz,
        double val1, double val2);
};
```

Now there is a problem; it would be really easy for the caller to accidentally transpose val1 and val2 and create a runtime bug. We can add a Params struct to allow named initialization and preclude this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   struct Params
   {
       std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;
       std::shared_ptr<Baz> baz;
       double val1;
       double val2
   };

    Foo(const Params& params);
};

// ...

std::shared_ptr<Foo> MakeDefaultFoo()
{
    Foo::Params p;
    p.bar = std::make_shared<Bar>();
    p.baz = std::make_shared<Baz>();
    p.val1 = 4.0;
    p.val2 = 3.0;
    return std::make_shared<Foo>(p);
}
```

But now we have the problem that the caller might forget to populate one of the fields in Params, which would not be detectable until runtime. struct initialization syntax or an initializer list would make it impossible to forget a field, but then we're back to relying on position!

Is there some trick that makes it possible to have the best of both worlds--compiler-enforced mandatory arguments that are assigned by name instead of position?

Comment: You could add `Params() : val1(0), val2(0) { }` so that if a value isn't set it at least has some sane default value.

Comment: @cdhowie When I'm forced to resort to that, I actually prefer *in*sane default values so that if this happens, the code will fail loud and fast. But failing at compile time would be best of all!

Comment: Or in all seriousness, maybe instead of `double` have two different named types for the two vals?

Comment: @dlf Is it acceptable to fail at runtime, but fail immediately when the `Foo` ctor is called?

Comment: @cdhowie That's better than nothing (and it's what I do now), but I would much rather fail at compile time. I don't really believe there is a solution to this problem without future changes to the language, but I guess you never know.

Comment: @dlf You could have setters for the `double` fields, and set a flag indicating that they were set, and add a `bool validate() const` method to `Params` that will return false if whatever validation you want to do fails. You can assert on that in your debug build.

Comment: @dlf Actually there may be a way to do this using `constexpr`. Let me tinker a bit and get back to you.

Comment: @Barry If you mean a simple inner wrapper struct with the same name as the parameter and a one-argument constructor that takes a double... that isn't a bad idea. It means a fair amount of extra typing, but seems like it might be viable.

Comment: You can probably do what you want to using [Boost.Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html); but be aware that it's quite preprocessor heavy.

Comment: @dlf Unfortunately, `constexpr` isn't going to work with `std::shared_ptr`. :| It may work with other types though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have a simple wrapper may work:

```
template <typename Tag, typename T>
struct Argument {
    explicit Argument( const T &val );
    T get() const;
};

class Foo {
public:
       struct Val1Tag;
       struct Val2Tag;
       typedef Argument<Val1Tag,double> Val1;
       typedef Argument<Val2Tag,double> Val2;

       Foo( Val1 v1, Val2 v2 );

};

Foo foo( Foo::Val1( 1.0 ), Foo::Val2( 2.3 ) );
```

Now types are explicit and you cannot swap them without getting compiler error.

Comment: -1 Except that `Val1` and `Val2` refer to the same type, so they are interchangeable.

Comment: [Here is a demo of what I mean](http://ideone.com/HDT7bS). This approach simply doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Nice fix and clever technique. Note that you do need to fully-qualify `Val1` outside of `Foo` though. (`Foo foo(Foo::Val1(...`)

Comment: Interesting question, are tag structures have to be complete? Quick search does not show answer here...

Comment: Not in this context, no. In fact you don't even have to name the tag template paramater (`template <typename, typename T>` would be fine). Type template parameters themselves do not require the type to be complete, rather it depends on what you do with that template parameter -- and in this case you do nothing at all with it.

Comment: This is a lot of hassle, obviously, but does seem to be the best that can be done within the constraints of the language as it currently exists.

Answer (score 2):

Very curious to see what cdhowie is tinkering with, but in the meantime, a simple wrapper with different types might solve some problems:

```
struct Val1 {
    explicit Val1(double v) : v(v) { }
    operator double() const { return v; }

    double v;
};

// copy for Val2

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::shared_ptr<Bar>& bar, const std::shared_ptr<Baz>& baz,
        Val1 val1, Val2 val2);
};
```

This way you can't mix them up, since you'll have to construct a Foo like:

```
Foo foo(bar, baz, Val1{3.0}, Val2{7.0});
```

It's a bunch of extra typing to make sure the types are different, and you definitely have to make sure you make the constructor `explicit` (or it defeats the point), but it helps.

Comment: Not the worst idea. Note that if you implement a base `template <typename T> class Wrapper ...` then you can simply inherit that and bring the base constructor in with `using`. Then `Val1` and `Val2` can be almost one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested)

```
template <typename tag, typename t>
struct param
{
   explicit param(t vv)
    : v(vv) {}
   param(const param& p)
    : v(p.v) {}
   t v; 
};

struct one{}; struct two {};
using paramone = param<one, double>;
using paramtwo = param<two, double>;

void somefunc (paramone p1, paramtwo p2)
{ ... };
void somefunc (paramtwo p2, paramone p1) 
{ somefunc(p1, p2); }

// using it

somefunc (2, 3); // bad
somefunc (paramone(2), paramtwo(3)); // good
somefunc (paramtwo(3), paramone(2)); // also good
```